# Find if at least one string of a list of strings hasn't a character (python)

Tags: python, any

I want to check if, among the elements of a list of strings, at least one of the element has not a "-" in it. I tried :

```
print not any("-" in elem for elem in my_list)
```

With:

```
my_list = ['gta', '---', '---', 'gta']
```

it should return `True` and with :

```
my_list = ['gt-', 'ac-', 'ca-', 'gt-']
```

It should return `False`. It's always `False` for now, is there a one-line command to do that ? I could choose the easy way and make my code on several lines, but I want to practice these kinds of commands :).

Comment: `not all(...)` instead of `not any(...)`.

Comment: Great ! Thanks ! I was also trying with ``elems= [seq[pos:pos+3] for seq in seqs if "-" not in seq[pos:pos+3]]`` and then check if len(elems) > 0 and it works too :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, since `not any` becomes `all not` you would need to use `not all`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re.findall` to check if the entire string in the list is composed of `"-"`:

```
import re
def check_string(s):
   return any(re.findall('^-+$', i) for i in s)

lists = [[['gta', '---', '---', 'gta'], True], [['gt-', 'ac-', 'ca-', 'gt-'], False]]
for a, b in lists:
   assert check_string(a) == b
```